# Getting preconfigured distribution failed

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

```
Oops, an error occurred!
Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::setTitle() must 
be of the type string, integer given, called in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\typo\typo3_src-
8.7.0\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Messaging\FlashMessage.php on line 67
```

I just finished installing `typo3` and want to proceed to get preconfigured distribution, but that error above appeared.

I'm completely new to typo3 and just want to compare typo3 with wordpress.

My setup is Windows 10, PHP 7.1.1, MariaDB 10.1.21.

What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you reported is reported as well as possible TYPO3 bug at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80762. Please continue at forge.typo3.org to get status updates about this issue.

The issue shows, that the list of mirrors cannot be retrieved from https://repositories.typo3.org/. This might happen, if your behind a firewall or the web-server is not configured to e.g. have `allow_url_fopen` enabled or `curl` module being installed for PHP.

The next maintenance release TYPO3 CMS 8.7.1 is planned for next Tuesday, April 18th 2017